# using cmake to cross compile gRPC for QNX

Tags: c++, cmake, grpc

Could not find a clear solution anywhere for gRPC cross compilation to arm from Linux. From all the posts/discussions I could find, it seems that cmake is the best option for cross compiling gRPC.

I created my own  toolchain cmake as per recommendation and when I run

> cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../qnx_tool_chain.cmake
>   -Dprotobuf_BUILD_TESTS=Off -DgRPC_INSTALL=Off

I see errors for boringssl compilation

> CMake Error at third_party/boringssl/CMakeLists.txt:305 (elseif):
>   given arguments:
>
> ```
> "STREQUAL" "x86_64"
> ```
>
> Unknown arguments specified

Any idea on latest recipe for cross-compiling grpc without having to reverse engineer from repo's top level CMakeLists.txt ?. Thanks

Comment: The [errorneous line](https://github.com/google/boringssl/blob/b29b21a81b32ec273f118f589f46d56ad3332420/CMakeLists.txt#L305) is `elseif (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR} STREQUAL "x86_64")`. It seems that your toolchain forget to set variable `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR`.

Comment: @Ysyvarev  thanks for the help. I Ran  "cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../qnx_toolchain.cmake -Dprotobuf_BUILD_TESTS=Off -DgRPC_INSTALL=Off -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=armv7"  but this generated TryRunResults.cmake under my build dir 
and I get failure message with 
"CMake Error: TRY_RUN() invoked in cross-compiling mode, please set the following cache variables appropriately:
   RUN_HAVE_STD_REGEX (advanced)
CMake Error at third_party/benchmark/CMakeLists.txt:183 (message):
  Failed to determine the source files for the regular expression backend".  Any  suggestion?

Comment: The project checks some things via compiling and running small programs and checking results. As you are cross-compiling, the program cannot be run. CMake ask you to fill the result "as if" the test program has been run on the target machine. The variable `RUN_HAVE_STD_REGEX` corresponds to running this file: [third_party/benchmark/cmake/std_regex.cpp](https://github.com/google/benchmark/blob/5b7683f49e1e9223cf9927b24f6fd3d6bd82e3f8/cmake/std_regex.cpp). See more about `try_run` in cross-compile mode in docs: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/try_run.html#behavior-when-cross-compiling

Comment: Thanks again @Tsyvarev, I made some progress with cmake but got stuck again half way through make , filed an issue with grpc folks at https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/16918 , the current problem seems to be with pthread lib, header usage in builds of thrid_party modules like boringssl. Not sure how to proceed, you have successfully cross compiled grpc before for QNX ? or for arm in general ?, looks like there is no known working procedure or  recipe anywhere (at least one that I know of)

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot give you any advice in this procedure: I have no experience in building gRPC.